# Is there a way to display stacked text in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to display stacked text in a QTextEdit? By stacked text, I mean fraction, or exponent

[image: for example]

Is there a way to achieve this without table or html conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Qt is using Unicode, and [UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) does have glyphs like ½ (i.e. `U+00BD VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF`).

However, I would indeed recommend switching to HTML.

You might also study the [source code of Qt](https://code.qt.io/cgit/) (it is open source) and subclass `QTextEdit` as wanted

Answer (score 1):

Qt supports a subset of HTML in its text handling. By default QTextEdit's `acceptRichText` property is true, so you should be able to set it's text to this:

```
"1<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>"
```

And it should display 1.5 as a fraction.